Output cell formula as a string
In Google Sheets, how do I output the formula of a cell as a string?
For example, something akin to the CELL function (which presently does not support this capability):
=CELL('formula',A1)
(I know that CTRL + ` displays the formulas, but this is not the same as being able to call them in a formula.)

formulatext()
